# questionon scanf() in C

Tags: c, function, scanf

What's the exacting meaning of the statement below,

```
if (scanf("%lf", &x) != 1)
```

I tried to input numbers, the condition is **true**,otherwise when I input nonumber character like 'a', the condition is **false**.

Could you tell me more about the `scanf()` and value `1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for `scanf()` on my system states:

> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

So, the result of `scanf()` in your case is 1 if there was a floating point number found, otherwise it is 0. The body of the `if` statement executes if the return value is not (`!=`) one.

Answer (score 3):

`man scanf`

> RETURN VALUE
>
> These  functions  return the number of input items successfully matched
>          and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
>          event of an early matching failure.
>
> The  value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either
>          the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.   EOF  is
>          also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator
>          for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is  set  indicate  the
>          error.

Answer (score 2):

> > if (scanf("%lf", &x) != 1)

If you enter the number 1 as your input, your condition should be **FALSE**;

" %lf "  is the conversion specifier that converts your numeric value to a floating point number

when your input is a non-numeric (ie. "A" or "Z" or "{" etc...) your compiler doesn't know how to convert a symbol to a real number.

**scanf** reads data entered by a user through a standard input device and stores it in a variable whose name and data type are determined by the programmer